# Bad interaction between Join and ListPlot (or Plot)

Tags: list-manipulation

When you write this code:

```
tab = {{1, 1}}; tab = Join[tab, {{2,2}}];
```

you expect to get the following table:

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}
```

but, if you write the following code instead:

```
tab = {{1, 1}}; tab = Join[tab, {{2, 2}}]; ListPlot[tab]
```

and after that, you check the elements of `tab`, it will contain these elements:

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}}
```

Why does it happen? Is it a kind of bug of *Mathematica*, or I do not understand how the `Join` function works? (I'm running version 10.0.0 on Windows 10.)

[image: Here I post a screenshot]

Comment: That's not what I get. You may need to clear `tab`. `Clear[tab]`

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10. If you place Clear on the same line, it works. But not if you do it in separate lines. I mean, what you say works if you write: Clear[tab]; tab = {{1, 1}}; tab = Join[tab, {{2, 2}}]; ListPlot[tab]

Comment: Does this happen on a fresh kernel? What version and OS are you on?

Comment: I am in Windows 10. Sorry, what do you mean with fresh kernel? It happens even if I place Clear["Global`*"]  in a previous line

Comment: Evaluation > Quit Kernel > Local

Comment: Sorry Young, I need more input for your answer. Do I have to search for that in a CMD?

Comment: No. In *Mathematica* using the menu bar at the top.

Comment: Sorry, to insist. Did you try what I posted? Which version and OS are you using?

Comment: Yes, I ran your code without issue. (I'm using Windows 7, 64-bit, V10.4)

Comment: Ok. Do not worry then. I will not put ListPlot after that. I can not be checking everytime I update my OS or Mathematica if it still happens

Comment: Does the workbook have any other lines of code?

Comment: Yes, I made a fresh document just to be sure, that only contains those lines. And I still have that problem.

Comment: Post a screen shot

Comment: I can confirm this problem in Mathematica 10.0.0. The strangest thing I ever saw.

Comment: Yes, I have the very same version 10.0.0. As I said before, it is a pain to be looking for this issue in every new version. I think that I will adopt as a practice not to write that extra line to be in the safe zone. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: No, still {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}}

Comment: Do not use 10.0.0.  Upgrade at least to 10.0.2, which should be a free upgrade to you.  Upgrade to the latest version if you have access.

Comment: I would put money on the damn Suggestions Bar (Predictive Interface) being the culprit.  [***Turn it off!***](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/121)  @C.E. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You were right! Posted it as an answer.

Comment: It's sad that such things happen. But is good  to know the solution. Thank you @Mr.Wizard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Mr. Wizard wisely suggested in his comment, the Suggestion Bar feature is the source of this bug. I have confirmed that turning it off removes the bug.

The canonical answer for Suggestion Bar troubles is found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/121). It shows how to turn it off, under Preferences > Interface.

Comment: It solved the problem, thank you.